# How to use `label_date_short`?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

How I am using wrongly `label_date_short` from scales package?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)


date_taille <- tibble(
  Taille = rep(c("taille_hiver", "taille_ete"), times = 2),
  Date_taille = c("2016-08-01", "2016-02-01", "2018-08-01", "2018-02-01") %>% as.Date()
)

ggplot(date_taille) +
  aes(x = Date_taille, y = Taille) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month", date_labels = label_date_short()) #or label_date()
#> Error in format(x, format = format, tz = tz): arguments inutilisés (format = format, tz = tz)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
#>  os       Manjaro Linux
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  C
#>  ctype    fr_FR.UTF-8
#>  tz       Indian/Reunion
#>  date     2022-05-12
#>  pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ /usr/bin/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  backports     1.4.1   2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  broom         0.8.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  cli           3.2.0   2022-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  colorspace    2.0-3   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  curl          4.3.2   2021-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  DBI           1.1.2   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dbplyr        2.1.1   2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.8   2022-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  farver        2.1.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.4)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  forcats     * 0.5.1   2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  generics      0.1.2   2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.5   2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  glue        * 1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  haven         2.5.0   2022-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  hms           1.1.1   2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  httr          1.4.2   2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  jsonlite      1.8.0   2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  knitr         1.38    2022-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  lubridate   * 1.8.0   2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  modelr        0.1.8   2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  R.cache       0.15.0  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  R.methodsS3   1.8.1   2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  R.oo          1.24.0  2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  R.utils       2.11.0  2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  readr       * 2.1.2   2022-01-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  readxl        1.4.0   2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.13    2022-03-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  rvest         1.0.2   2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  scales      * 1.2.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.3)
#>  styler        1.7.0   2022-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  tibble      * 3.1.6   2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#>  tidyr       * 1.2.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.2   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.1   2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.5)
#>  tzdb          0.3.0   2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.0)
#>  vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xfun          0.30    2022-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xml2          1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#> 
#>  [1] /home/annadoizy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1
#>  [2] /usr/lib/R/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using it wrongly, but you should use the `labels` argument instead of the `date_labels` one:

```r
ggplot(date_taille) +
  aes(x = Date_taille, y = Taille) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "month", labels = label_date_short())
```

[image]